# php / MySQL - Displaying only one header for items

Tags: php, html, mysql, tableheader

I am working on a food website and have noticed an issue when I display the users cart, currently the table header is called per item which is taken from mySQL, which looks like this:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
function cart() {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0){
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;?>
                <center>
                <table class='menufinal' border=0 width=75%>
                <th>Remove Item</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Line Total</th>
                <tr>
                <td><?echo '<a href="cart.php?delete=' .$id.'"><img src="x.png"></a><br>'?></td>
                <td><?echo $get_row['name']?></td>
                <td><?echo '&pound' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2);?></td>
                <td><?echo '<a href="cart.php?remove=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none">- </a>' .$value. '<a href="cart.php?add=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"> +</a>' ?> </td>
                <td> <?echo '&pound ' . number_format($sub, 2);?> </td>
                </tr>
                <?
            }
        } 
        if (empty($total)) {

            if (empty($sub)) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $total = $sub;
            }
        } else {
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
}
if (!empty($total)){
    echo '<br>Total: &pound' . number_format($total, 2) . '<br>';
    echo '<div id="dorc"><p><a href="index.php"><img src="dishes.png" width="240" height="152"></a> <img src="spacer.png" width="200"> <a href="checkout.php"><img src="checkout.png" width="240" height="152"></a>';
}
else {
    header ('Location: index.php');
}
}
```

My question is how can I get it to display the table header only once and also why is there an additional item being printed to the bottom of the screen alone?

Comment: You have an opening `<table>` inside your loop, but no closing tags at all - I doubt it's the problem, but I don't think it'll help.

Comment: @andrewsi this helped move the item stuck at the bottom so thanks a lot :D I still have the reoccurring header issue, though

Comment: Your `<th>` tags should be outside the loop, too - they also need to be wrapped in a `<tr>` tag, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the table and header tags outside of the loop.

Do something like:

```
<table>
<th></th> #define all table headers

for each item:
   <tr>
     <td>item info</td>...
   </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, however make sure that your table opening tag & table header are OUTSIDE of your while loop.

A "while loop" will do the same function repeatedly until it's through. In OP's case, it will recreate the table and headers over and over again.

Comment: I tried moving the tags you listed outside the while loop however the headers are still being duplicated :(

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php 
function cart() {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0){
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));?>
                <center>
                <table class='menufinal' border=0 width=75%>
                <th>Remove Item</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Line Total</th>
            <?php while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;?>
                <tr>
                <td><?echo '<a href="cart.php?delete=' .$id.'"><img src="x.png"></a><br>'?></td>
                <td><?echo $get_row['name']?></td>
                <td><?echo '&pound' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2);?></td>
                <td><?echo '<a href="cart.php?remove=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none">- </a>' .$value. '<a href="cart.php?add=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"> +</a>' ?> </td>
                <td> <?echo '&pound ' . number_format($sub, 2);?> </td>
                </tr>
                <?
            }
        } 
        if (empty($total)) {

            if (empty($sub)) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $total = $sub;
            }
        } else {
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
}
if (!empty($total)){
    echo '<br>Total: &pound' . number_format($total, 2) . '<br>';
    echo '<div id="dorc"><p><a href="index.php"><img src="dishes.png" width="240" height="152"></a> <img src="spacer.png" width="200"> <a href="checkout.php"><img src="checkout.png" width="240" height="152"></a>';
}
else {
    header ('Location: index.php');
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but unfortunately the headings are still duplicating :( So frustrating! Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: try to move table starting tag & other after `function cart() {`